# How to do rpush operation in then-redis?

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

1. How can I do rpush operation with then redis and retrieve all data back?
2. How to do hlist operations in then-redis?

Answer (score 1):

rpush operation api is currently not available by then-redis .You can probably write your own code for command.js in same. There is no operation like hlist as well you can again write support for LRANGE or RRANGE as per you requirement and use it to retrieve all the results.

Answer (score 1):

for question 1 :
you can use the [multi command](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis/#clientmulticommands) :

```
 client.multi()
    .rpush("yourlist","value")
    .lrange("yourlist", 0,-1,function (err, replies) {
        // here get le list content from replies
    })
    .exec(function (err, replies) {
        //...
    });
```

Question 2 by Chhavi : rpush operation api is currently not available by then-redis